# Android - inserting data into mysql through android

Tags: android

I'm trying to verify username ,password through mysql server and the code for the same is as follows:

I have created the web service in php and the namespace and other values i have mentioned as shown in below code:

```
   package com.example.androidloginexampleactivity;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.StrictMode;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class AndroidLoginExampleActivity extends Activity {
        private TextView textView;
            /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_login_example);
            Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
            //this.accessWebService(textView);
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    LoginAction lgn = new LoginAction();
                    lgn.execute();

                                }
            });

        }


        private class LoginAction extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
        {
            protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
             {
                String webResponse = "";
                try{
                final String NAMESPACE = "urn:stockserver";
                final String URL = "http://localhost/stockserver1.php?wsdl";

                //private final String URL = " http://10.0.2.2:8080/WebApplication2/Login?Tester";
                final String SOAP_ACTION = "urn:stockserver#getStockQuote";
                final String METHOD_NAME = "getStockQuote";

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_userName);
            String user_Name = userName.getText().toString();
            EditText userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_password);
            String user_Password = userPassword.getText().toString();

            //Pass value for userName variable of the web service
            PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
            unameProp.setName("userName");//Define the variable name in the web service method
            unameProp.setValue(user_Name);//set value for userName variable
            unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
            request.addProperty(unameProp);//Pass propert   ies to the variable

            //Pass value for Password variable of the web service
            PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
            passwordProp.setName("password");
            passwordProp.setValue(user_Password);
            passwordProp.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(passwordProp);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER10);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

                TextView result1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
                result1.setText(response.toString());

                }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Completed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }   

            return webResponse; 
        }
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
               textView.setText(result);
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Completed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
    }
```

The following error i'm getting:

```
   10-08 12:51:28.639: W/dalvikvm(2245): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
   10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
   10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
   10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
   10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
   10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
   10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
   10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
   10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
   10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
   10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
   10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
   10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
   10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
   10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):  at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:324)
   10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
   10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
   10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):  at com.example.androidloginexampleactivity.AndroidLoginExampleActivity$LoginAction.doInBackground(AndroidLoginExampleActivity.java:92)
   10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):  at com.example.androidloginexampleactivity.AndroidLoginExampleActivity$LoginAction.doInBackground(AndroidLoginExampleActivity.java:1)
   10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
   10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
   10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):  ... 4 more
```

please help me to resolve this, thanks in advance....

Comment: Do not try to update UI or show popup in doInBackground method. Just update all the UI related operations in onPostExecute method only.

Comment: also, once this is fixed, you'll get an issue with localhost being your android device, not your server

Comment: last point, toasting an exception is useless. log it, mail it, write it to a file, do whatever, but displaying it roughly to the user is always bad.

Comment: printing a stacktrace, on the other hand, provides handy information in case of debugging

Comment: Remove the toast from catch () in the doInBackground, and use Log to print the error or e.printStackTrace().

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error because you are trying to do something that requires access to the UI thread from your `AsyncTask` doInBackground() method. For example, you see towards the end of the doInBackground() method you try to set the text on a `TextView`. This must be done on the UI thread.

What you should do is move everything that requires the UI threat - like setting/geting values from UI elements to onPostExecute. This runs on the UI thread and should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing following two lines in doInBackground method of AsyncTask

```
Looper.myLooper();
Looper.prepare();
```

Also do all the UI things in Handler.

Answer (score 0):

You getting a looper.prepare error, because you are calling a toast from an async task. Remove the toast from onPostExecute() and even doInBackground() (this is the one throwing the error).. For tracking purposes you could use Log.i method

Comment: You can call toast from onPostExecute with the appropriate context. There's nothing wrong with doing this.

Comment: these lines said so , thats why i mentioned it

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
      10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):  at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:324)
   10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
   10-08 12:51:28.749: E/AndroidRuntime(2245):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)

Comment: I reconfirmed, it is not possible to display a toast while in the doInBaxkground atleast, didnt confirm onPostExecute.

Comment: You can't toast in doInBackground. Toast uses the UI thread. It's the same reason I state above. Because onPostExecute runs on the UI thread you can toast from that method. As I said in my answer all UI actions need to be moved to onPostExecute. That will fix your problem.